# How can I change some jQuery code to make a rectangle draggable?

Tags: jquery

Below is some code that uses jQuery. Clicking a button will copy an original rectangle.

How can I make all rectangles draggable?

CSS:

```
.my_rectangle {
  width: 200px;
  background: pink;   
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="original_rectangle" class="my_rectangle">original rectangle</div>
<button id="copy_button">Copy</button>
```

Javascript:

```
var count = 1
$("#copy_button").click(function() {
  copy = $("#original_rectangle").clone()
  copy.removeAttr("id").html("copy " + count).appendTo("body")
  count += 1
})
```

(Acknowledgment: Thank you to user Haochi for the original version of the code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
copy.removeAttr("id").html("copy " + count).appendTo("body")
```

...to this:

```
copy.removeAttr("id").html("copy " + count).appendTo("body").draggable();
```

This assumes you're using the jQuery UI library.

Separately, it's a good idea to terminate your statements with semicolons. JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion can occasionally lead to tricky bugs. The classic example:

```
function f(){
  return
  {
    some : 'value'
  }
}
```

Of course, in this example the bracket style conspires with semicolon insertion to create the ambiguity, so it's an argument against both semicolon insertion and placing opening brackets on new lines.

Comment: I use Python. (For readers who do not know, newlines in Python act like semicolons in 
J.) Code is more concise without semicolons. Thank you for the advice and example about semicolons in Javascript.

Comment: In the above comment, "J." is Javascript. I may have accidentally hit the enter button before finishing.

Comment: @Winston, yeah, your code obviously feels more Pythonic without the semicolons. But in Python the newline token essentially has the role of the semicolon, so there's no guessing. In JavaScript... well, it can get confusing. Check out the [ECMA docs (PDF)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf), section 7.9.1. I'd rather use the semicolons and be certain of the outcome.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using the jQuery UI library for draggables, otherwise you will end up re-implementing much of the same thing they have done.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

Creating a draggble would look something like this:

```
$("#original_rectangle").draggable();
```

Comment: +1. @Adam Ayres. Thank you. I used your code and Ken Redler's code. Your code makes the original rectangle draggable, and his code makes the copied rectangles draggable.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) it would look something like this:

```
var count = 1
$("#copy_button").click(function() {
  copy = $("#original_rectangle").clone()
  copy.removeAttr("id").addClass("dragMe ui-widget-content").html("copy " + count).appendTo("body")
  count += 1
})

$("dragMe").draggable();
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com). Check out their demo of [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) to see if its what you're looking for.